# Assigning the different row to another matrix after comparing two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indices

i have two matrices

r=10,000x2
q=10,000x2

i have to find out those rows of q which are one value or both values(as it is a two column matrix)  different then r and allocate them in another matrix, right now i am trying this.i cannot use isequal because i want to know those rows 
 which are not equal this code  gives me the individual elements not the complete rows different
can anyone help please

```
if r(:,:)~=q(:,:) 
       IN= find(registeredPts(:,:)~=q(:,:))
end
```

Comment: can you give an example output for a small test case?

Comment: e=[1,2;3,4;5,6], f=[1,2;3,5;5,6] now i want to store row 2 which is different in both matrices in another matrix

Comment: Do you want to store both rows (since they are different)?

Comment: no i just want to store row of f which r different from e

Comment: ismember takes 1 and 1.0000 as different how to handle it?

Comment: They are probably different (although only slightly). Try `3*0.1 == 0.3` to see my point.

Comment: actually i have to apply this on grid , i dont want this much slight difference to be taken as a difference, if u know a way out

Comment: ok thanku sir i will apply and then update here if it works

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). Is this what you want? Here you get the values from `q` in rows that are different from `r`.

```
q=[1,2;3,4;5,6]
r=[1,2;3,5;5,6]

x = q(sum(ismember(q,r),2) < 2,:)
x =
     3     4
```

What this do:
`ismember` creates an array with 1's in the positions where `q == r`, and 0 in the remaining positions. `sum(.., 2)` takes the column sum of each of these rows. If the sum is less than 2, that row is included in the new array.

## Update

If the values might differ some due to floating point arithmetic, check out [`ismemberf` from the file exchange.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf) I haven't tested it myself, but it looks good.